# What is causing SSH to stop working over wired connection when I plug in a wireless usb card?

Tags: wifi, network-interface, arch-arm, bananapi

I have a Banana Pi running some custom Arch distribution by Ryad.

I plugged in a cheap wifi dongle with the Ralink RT5370N chipset.

Under /etc/systemd/network:

10-eth0.network

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
RouteMetric=10
```

20-wlan0.network

```
[Match]
Name=wlan0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
RouteMetric=20
```

Whenever I plug in the wireless usb card, I have trouble "SSHing" into the thing. Existing secure shell sessions continue to work normally. What would cause this?

networkctl (before plugging in)

```
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged
  2 eth0             ether              routable    pending
  3 tunl0            tunnel             off         unmanaged

3 links listed.
```

networkctl (after plugging in–takes a long time to respond)

```
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     pending
  2 eth0             ether              routable    pending
  3 tunl0            tunnel             off         pending
  4 wlan0            wlan               off         configuring

4 links listed.
```

`wireless_tools` is installed.

`lsmod` yields the following possibly relevant results:

```
rt5370sta             673082  0
rt2800usb              13632  0
rt2800lib              48613  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00usb              11127  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              42474  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              247524  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
```

Comment: Which addresses is the SSH server set up to listen on? How does the routing table change when you plug in the thing?

Comment: @tripleee I never changed the default settings, so unless Ryad did something, it should list on port 22 of any address. I am not sure how to compare routing tables. Do you mean like `iptables-save` before and after to get the printout?

Comment: The output of `route -n` should be sufficient; if you have anything nonstandard in `iptables`, that would be good to mention, too. A `netstat` listing showing what's listening to port 22 and more importantly where exactly (0.0.0.0 or a designated address? IP4 or IP6?) would be useful, too. Oh and maybe an excerpt from the system log around the plug-in event, too.